# Optional caching in python - Wrapping a cachetools decorator with arguments

Tags: python, caching, decorator, wrapper, cachetools

I'm using the `cachetools` library and I would like to wrap the decorator form this library and add a class self argument to enable/disable the caching at the class level e.e. `MyClass(enable_cache=True)`

An example usage would be something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, enable_cache=True):
        self.enable_cache = enable_cache
        self.cache = cachetools.LRUCache(maxsize=10)
    
    @cachetools.cachedmethod(operator.attrgetter('cache'))
    def calc(self, n):
        return 1*n
```

I'm not sure how to keep the cache as a shared self class object and allow for the enable_cache flag within my own wrapper decorator using this library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the answer is actually quite simple - you set the cache to `None`.

```
import cachetools
import operator

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, enable_cache=True):
        self.cache = cachetools.LRUCache(maxsize=10) if enable_cache else None
    
    @cachetools.cachedmethod(operator.attrgetter('cache'))
    def calc(self, n):
        print("Calculating", n)
        return 1*n
    
    
m1 = MyClass(True)
m1.calc(2)
m1.calc(2)
m1.calc(3)
m1.calc(3)
print("now without")
m2 = MyClass(False)
m2.calc(2)
m2.calc(2)
m2.calc(3)
m2.calc(3)
```

Output:

```
Calculating 2
Calculating 3
now without
Calculating 2
Calculating 2
Calculating 3
Calculating 3
```

---

More flexible you can do it do it by wrapping the cache or by making a whole new decorator:

```
import cachetools
import operator

def flexible_cache(cache):
    def cache_wrapper(self):
        if self.enable_cache:
            return cache(self)
        return None
    return cache_wrapper

def optional_cache(cache, *args, **kwargs):
    return cachetools.cachedmethod(flexible_cache(cache), *args, **kwargs)
    

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, enable_cache=True):
        self.enable_cache = enable_cache
        self.cache = cachetools.LRUCache(maxsize=10) # Now the None part is handled by the decorators
    
    @cachetools.cachedmethod(flexible_cache(operator.attrgetter('cache')))
    def calc2(self, n):
        print("Calculating2", 2*n)
        return 2*n
    
    @optional_cache(operator.attrgetter('cache'))
    def calc3(self, n):
       print("Calculating3", 2*n)
       return 2*n
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to defer the choice to decorate to the user who will instantiate your class. Then `setattr` is your friend. I demonstrate its use with a custom decorator, but the principle is the same.

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{result = }")
        return result
    return inner

class Asd:
    def __init__(self, decorate=False):
        if decorate:
            setattr(self, "method", decorator(getattr(self, "method")))
    
    def method(self):
        return 42
```

```
>>> asd = Asd(decorate=False)
>>> asd.method()
42
>>> asd = Asd(decorate=True)
>>> asd.method()
result = 42
42
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired functionality of enabling or disabling caching at the class level using the `cachetools` library, you can create a custom decorator that wraps the `cachedmethod` decorator. Here's an example implementation:

```py
import cachetools
import operator

def class_cachedmethod(cache_key, maxsize=128):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.cache = cachetools.LRUCache(maxsize=maxsize)
        
        def wrapper(method):
            if not getattr(cls, 'enable_cache', True):
                return method
            return cachetools.cachedmethod(operator.attrgetter(cache_key))(method)
        
        setattr(cls, cache_key, wrapper)
        return cls
    return decorator
```

In the code above, we define a `class_cachedmethod` decorator that takes a `cache_key` argument, which represents the cache attribute name within the class. The decorator returns another decorator that wraps the class and its methods.

Here's how you can use it with your example:

```py
@class_cachedmethod('cache')
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, enable_cache=True):
        self.enable_cache = enable_cache

    def cache(self, method):
        return method

    @cache
    def calc(self, n):
        return 1 * n
```

In this example, we apply the `class_cachedmethod` decorator to the `MyClass` class, specifying `'cache'` as the cache attribute name. The `calc` method is decorated with the `@cache` decorator, which internally checks the `enable_cache` flag and decides whether to apply caching or not.

If `enable_cache` is `True`, the `calc` method will be cached using the `cachetools.cachedmethod` decorator with the cache attribute `operator.attrgetter('cache')`. If `enable_cache` is `False`, the `calc` method will be returned without caching.

By default, the cache size is set to 128, but you can adjust it by modifying the `maxsize` parameter in the `class_cachedmethod` decorator or in the `LRUCache` instantiation inside the decorator.

Comment: I get an error here `TypeError: cache() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'` when the code gets interpreted not when it runs, on the @cache def calc line.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW yeah now that I look at it again I think your right, copy paste from the docs that entire last portion. It looks really close thou as far as an answer, I'm just now sure how to pass the method from the class function to that decorator